# Unable to override module_catalog items.phtml

Tags: overrides, magento-2.1.1

I'm trying to make some minor changes to the template found at  `vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/list/items.phtml`.

So I've created the a new file `app/design/frontend/xxx/yyy/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list/items.phtml` made my changes, run `rm -rf var/view_preprocessed/* var/cache/* var/generation/* pub/static/frontend/Monsoon/* && php bin/magento cache:flush` and `magento setup:static-content:deploy`. However,  I don't see the changes and when I enable debugging Magento is still referenceing `vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/list/items.phtml`.

I've been using Magento for less than a month so perhaps I'm missing something super obvious.

Answer (score 1):

Triple check for typos in the folders and file name. More often than not that is the reason for this issues. Other than that you can debug this method which is where Magento tried to find the template file https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2-develop/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Element/Template.php#L259

It triggers for every block in the system so you'd have to put a conditional break point to make sure it only stops in the block you are interested in.

Answer (score 0):

Confirm that your theme is otherwise active. That is, confirm that another template or a layout update from your theme is being loaded.

Make a temporary modification to the file in the vendor directory. This will confirm that the web server is loading the latest changes.

I would make sure PHP is set to display errors - `ini_set('display_errors', 1);` in index.php. Also confirm that there are no related errors in the Javascript console.

Beyond that, it seems like you are following the correct steps. I would further consult the [Magento Dev Docs](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/templates/template-override.html).

Comment: Thanks for the response. 1) I'm pretty sure the theme is active. If I update `app/design/frontend/xxx/yyy/Magento_Theme/templates/html/copyright.phtml` I see the change. However, I've also encountered another issue on the same page (individual product) when attempting to resize the gallery image. Perhaps you are on to something here. 2) If I make a change the file in the vendor directory I see the change. 3) I'll look into the php errors but I can confirm that there are no js errors.